# Loading Dojo AMD module fails under TheIntern test framework

Tags: javascript, dojo, intern

I am creating a demo for using the [TheIntern](https://github.com/theintern/intern) test framework. 
When I try to load test module *demo/intests/data* I keep getting this error:

```
Defaulting to "console" reporter
Error: Failed to load module demo/intests/data from http://localhost:8081/dojo_playground/tutorials/demo/intests/data.js (parent: *12)
    at /home/bogdanbiv/.nvm/v0.10.24/lib/node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/dojo.js:754:12
    at fs.js:207:20
    at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
```

However, accessing this file from the browser is ok, here are the server logs:

```
~/Projects$ http-server -p 8081 ./
Starting up http-server, serving ./ on port: 8081
Hit CTRL-C to stop the server
[Sat, 22 Mar 2014 13:06:55 GMT] "GET /dojo_playground/tutorials/demo/intests/data.js" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/32.0.1700.107 Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36"
```

I tried creating a module as simple as possible in *demo/intests/data*:

```
define({
    greeting: "Hello!",
    howAreYou: "How are you?"
});

define([], function(){});
```

Data:

- Application root is at $HOME/Projects/dojo_playground/tutorials/
- Module *demo/intests/data* is
  located at *$HOME/Projects/dojo_playground/tutorials/demo/intests/data.js*
- Intern configuration: http://pastebin.com/hyi55qp7.
- webserver is Nodejitsu's http-server, which is run run from localhost, webroot is $HOME/Projects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two issues here:

1. You’re trying to load a module from the filesystem using an HTTP URL as the path. This won’t work, for hopefully obvious reasons. You need to fix your configuration so that it is not trying to generate URLs, but rather relative paths that can be used both with a filesystem or with a network request, by not specifying an absolute URL for the loader’s `baseUrl` property.
2. You can’t define two values for a single module; you should have no more than one `define` call per module.

Comment: 1: Indeed baseUrl was the culprit for that error. 
2: The dual 'define' calls were just examples of what I have tried so far. Only one was active at runtime. 
Could you please have a look at this question too, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22652975/how-do-i-configure-the-webserver-inside-theintern ?